# Converting Dates in MSAccess

Tags: date, ms-access-2010

Pretty new and trying to learn more about MSAccess. Is there a way that I can convert a date from 12/7/2014 to December 2014? I currently have tons of dates in each month that I want to group by month.

Thanks!
Malcolm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Format(Date,"mmmm yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use different Format for the date in access

> Format (#17/04/2004#, "Short Date") Result: '17/04/2004'
>
> Format (#17/04/2004#, "Long Date") Result: 'April 17, 2004'
>
> Format (#17/04/2004#, "yyyy/mm/dd") Result: '2004/04/17'

For you example you could use

> Format (Date,"Long Date")